# Why does operator new can't construct multidimensional array of non-constant size?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-length-array

I can write operator new for one-dimensional array as follows:

```
int n{3};
new int[n];
```

It allocates at least `sizeof(int) * n` bytes. But when I want to create two and more dimensional array, only first dimension may be non-constant:

```
int n{3};
new int[n][3]; //ok
new int[n][n]; //error;
```

Why such restrictions are take place? Are there any difficulties to determine, that it is at least `sizeof(int) * n * n` bytes to allocate?

Comment: You can't have VLA with auto storage, why allow it for dynamic storage?

Comment: StoryTeller, but for one-dimensional arrays it works, why isn't it allowed for more dimensional arrays?

Comment: You don't have VLAs, which means you can't have pointers to VLAs `int (*)[n]`, and that is what such an expression will need to return.

Comment: In the end, it all comes down to the fact that the C++ standard committee didn't find VLAs a needed addition to C++.  I don't have access to the minutes of those meetings, so I can't tell you why.

Comment: @StoryTeller allowing VLA with dynamic storage but not auto is a viable option (one of the common complains about VLA is that it risks a stack overflow).

Comment: @M.M To allow it for dynamic storage, all you really need is VLA pointers and references. (Just reinterpret "flat" memory as "mult-dimensional). But I don't see the merit in allowing it in one form or another, myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ type system does not include arrays with runtime bound. This is a very complicated thing to do, considering that it will have implications for templates and overload resolution. There have been proposals but none has progressed to being accepted for standardization.

So `T[n]` is not a valid type.  However it can be used in a `new`-expression because there is a special case for it. The `new`-expression can be either:

- `new X`, where `X` is a type
- `new T[n]`, where `T` is a type and `n` is not a constant expression.

Note that both cases are needed because `T[n]` is not a type but we want to allow that in a `new`-expression.

The second point needs a little bit more explanation. It actually uses the C++ infix notation, so if `T` is an array or function type, the `[n]` will be in a different place. For example `new int[n][3]` is OK , which is the same as `typedef int T[3]; new T[n]`. But `new int[3][n]` is not.

If we did allow `new int[3][n]`, what would the return type be? `int (*)[n]` is not part of the C++ type system as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in this case is not about determining how much memory to allocate. That part is actually easy, as you noted it yourself.

The problem is organizing access to such an array afterwards. If you know, multidimensional arrays in C++ are implemented as linear (one-dimensional) arrays with index remapping. For example, when you declare

```
int a[N][M];
```

the compiler actually creates an `int [N * M]` array under the hood. And when you later access it as `a[i][j]`, the latter is simply implicitly translated into access to `a[i * M + j]`. C++ compilers insist on knowing the value of `M` at compile time (meanwhile, note that the value of `N` does not participate in the index recalculation formula at all).

This is the reason why in contexts where arrays decay to pointers the first size of multi-dimensional array does not matter, while the second, third and further sizes have to be compile-time constants. This is what determines the restrictions imposed on `new []` as well.

P.S. C language supports Variable Length Arrays, which allow all sizes to be run-time values. This requires additional efforts under the hood, like storing the run-time values of `M` and `N` together with the array `a` from the above example. This was eventually deemed unsuitable for C++.